# emulator does not open up home screen

Tags: android

My emulator does not open up.

I have seen other questions in stackoverflow similar to my question, but I didn't get any help. Also I replaced my 1GB RAM with 2GB. But its still the same. The emulator does not show the home screen. I am using P4 3.0 GHZ processor. I also tried assigning 1024 mib to sd for a avd. But it is still the same.

I am using Android SDK 4.0 and Eclipse Juno.

Comment: Can somebody help me i am not able to run a sample program as well i am new new to android and looking for help...

Comment: Please run the emulator from the terminal/console and post all the output that is being generated. Without this it's a guessing game.
The emulator is located in SDK_PATH/tools/emulator

Comment: [2012-08-19 14:38:39 - Demo] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2012-08-19 14:45:34 - Demo] ------------------------------
[2012-08-19 14:45:34 - Demo] Android Launch!
[2012-08-19 14:45:34 - Demo] adb is running normally.
[2012-08-19 14:45:34 - Demo] Performing com.demo.MainActivity activity launch
[2012-08-19 14:45:34 - Demo] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'android' is available on emulator 'emulator-5554'
[2012-08-19 14:45:34 - Demo] Uploading Demo.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-08-19 14:45:36 - Demo] Installing Demo.apk...

Comment: Its really very frustating i am trying since the past 1 week just to run a sample program of android.Even tried replacing my 1Gb ram with a new 2 Gb ram.However there no help.All i can see as output is the emulator i have shown below.Also waited for more than 30 minutes however no output is displayed...Can someone please help me its so frustating..

Answer (score 1):

Just wait, your machine isn't very much emulator friendly.

It only takes a bit longer the first time you run it.

Comment: ,its not a bit longer it takes more than 3 hours and even then it does not turn up

Answer (score 0):

it is a same problem that i have got.

but i solved it by,when i first start my emulator from AVD then i do not change it's scale,
then when it start as its default scale property then i close it and start one more time and scale it as i need it than it will work perfectly.

Comment: Still the same i tried to sclae it to  -scale 0.5.But still the same.What scale value did u apply?

Comment: i have scaled my emulator 0.6.

Comment: yes dattu i tried doing that also...do i need to change my system?

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot of options to get the emulator up and running. Cleaned/re-started/adb killstart and all this unfortunately did not work for me. I was trying with API level 20 (Android 4.4W ).
But, nothing helped. Hence i tried with API 17/18/19 ( Android 4.2,4.3 etc. ). Finally 4.3.1 and API 18 worked for me and my emulator started fine.